# Passing string to view asyncronously (Ajax)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json

I am trying to make a view where the user will create a date associated with an article. When a user enters a barcode it should display the name of the article for the purpose of helping the user making sure it is the right barcode which is entered.

**The method in the DateController where it gets the string and passes it on:**

```
public JsonResult GetArticleName(long barcode)
{
    ArticleDbContext artdb = new ArticleDbContext();
    Article art = (Article) artdb.Articles.Where(a => a.Barcode == barcode).First();
    return Json(art.Name, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**The javascript to fetch the data:**

```
$("#ArticleBarcode").change(function (event) {
    var URL = "/Date/GetArticleName";
    $.getJSON(URL, { Barcode: $("#ArticleBarcode").val() }, function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (index, d) {
            $("#ArticleName").html(d);
        });
    });
});
```

*The problem is that it seems like it does not pass any value at all. What am I to do?*

**PS: ArticleBarcode change event doesn't seem to fire.**

**EDIT:**

The entire Create.cshtml

```
model DatoCheckerMvc.Models.Date

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Opret ny";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Opret</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Date", FormMethod.Post, new { }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)


    <script type="text/javascript">
        function validationFunction() {
            var isValid = true;
            if (!$("#ArticleBarcode").val() || $("#ArticleBarcode").val() == "" || $("#ArticleBarcode").val().match("^\d+$")) {
                isValid = false;
            }
            if (!$("#RunDate").val() || $("#RunDate").val() == "" || $("#RunDate").val().match("((?:(?:[0-2]?\\d{1})|(?:[3][01]{1}))[-:\\/.](?:[0]?[1-9]|[1][012])[-:\\/.](?:(?:[1]{1}\\d{1}\\d{1}\\d{1})|(?:[2]{1}\\d{3})))(?![\\d])")) {
                isValid = false;
            }

            if (isValid) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(window).keydown(function (event) {
                if ((event.keyCode == 13) && (validationFunction() == false)) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    return false;
                }
            });

            $("#ArticleBarcode").change(function (event) {
                alert("executed");
                $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetArticleName", "Date")', { Barcode: $("#ArticleBarcode").val() }, function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (index, d) {
                        $("#ArticleName").html(d);
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    </script>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Dato</legend>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ArticleBarcode)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ArticleBarcode, null, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ArticleBarcode)
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <div class="editor-label">
                    <label for="ArticleName">Varenavn</label>
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    <div id="ArticleName">

                    </div>


         </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RunDate)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.RunDate, null, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RunDate)
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p>
        <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Opret" />
    </p>
</fieldset>

}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Tilbage", "Index") </div>

@section Scripts 
{
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval") 
}
```

Comment: What does the service receive as request? What do you send as request? (check with netpanel in your browser devtools). What does the client receive as response? What does the server send as response?

Comment: $.getJSON is used for getting JSON data from server then how it is used for your case ?

Comment: @SivaRajini he's using it to get JSON data, passing the barcode parameter to the endpoint.

Comment: Try using blur event instead of change and see if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using the same name as used in controller as shown below

```
$.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetArticleName", "Date")', { barcode: $("#ArticleBarcode").val() }, function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (index, d) {
            $("#ArticleName").html(d);
        });
    });
```

and using "/Date/GetArticleName" may create problem for you when you deply!

Comment: It is implemented and it still does not work. I have inserted an alert in the article change event and it does not seem to fire.

Comment: then I guess some problem with your jquery or check if there is any spelling mistake while binding event in jquery @Highace2

Comment: There is no jquery problem or spelling mistake. However note that the ArticleBarcode is a input generated by the html helper TextBoxFor.

Comment: can you post your mvc code I mean that textbox code?

Comment: JQuery was imported at the bottom of the layout page.

Comment: it says ressource not found with a 404 code. I can't figure out why.

Comment: I told you some problem with your jquery coz you said even event is not firing so it meant jquery is not binded successfully

Comment: Yes but can you tell me why it cannot find the ressource? It shows the right url.